# If I respec will my research slots be preserved?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

So if I have the woodworking upgrade for 2 traits to be researched and both slots are occupied,  if I respec and don't upgrade that skill again,  will those 2 currently researching traits finish normally/correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the game will allow you to finish both, although at a slower pace.

The passive ability only dictates how many research jobs you can actually start while others are still in progress and how long they take.

So if you respec the timers will increase, but that's essentially the only downside of not getting those passives again (aside from not being able to start multiple jobs).

Answer (score 0):

Answer appears to be yes, despite having 2 items currently researching the bar will say 1/1